# How to display italics with lmodern package

Tags: fonts, italic, latin-modern

When I use the `lmodern` package, I cannot get italics to display. Here is an example:

```
\listfiles      % added to get in the log the package versions
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
non-italic \emph{should be italic} itshape: {\itshape should be italic} 
textit: \textit{should be italic}
\end{document}
```

None of the "should be italic" are italic. If I remove the `lmodern` package, all of these are italic. How can I get italic characters with the `lmodern` package?

I'm compiling with pdflatex (or pdfeTex 3.141592-1.21a-2.2 according to the log).

\listfiles provides:

```
article.cls    2004/02/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo    2004/02/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX file (size option)
```

There are no errors or warnings in the output.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Shows up as italics for me, so not sure what is going on. How are you compiling this document?

Comment: Maybe you find something in the LOG that font files/faces are missing … Please add the system and distribution you are using (and maybe a `\listfiles`) to your question

Comment: I second Peter's request. Please say which format you use (pdfLaTeX, XeTeX, luaTeX, other?) and show the versions of the packages. (You can get this information in the log if you put `\listfiles` before `\begin{document}`.)

Comment: You should also report the last part of the log file, where the file list is shown.

Comment: I updated with \listfiles output. I guess these are out of date? How can I update these, on Red Hat 4.1.2-52, no root?

Comment: @pnj: The `.log` should show 4 files: `article.cls` (2007/10/19 v1.4h), `size10.clo` (2007/10/19 v1.4h), `lmodern.sty` (2009/10/30 v1.6), `ot11mr.fd` (2009/10/31 v1.6). So yes, your setup is out-of-date. Assuming that you're running TeX Live, [download the latest version from TUG](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html).

Comment: he presumably _is_ running tex live, but he did say he doesn't have superuser privs.  sucking a tl package from a ctan mirror won't help (a) because he won't have access to tlmgr, (b) because his system is obviously out of date, so tlmgr wouldn't install a current version (as from a mirror) even if he could use it.  installing a new lm package "by hand" isn't really a good way to proceed, but it is described in the uk faq.

Comment: Apologies for my own lack of clarity about what I'm running. I'm using a server set up by my school (RCE @harvard), and I am compiling with command-line pdflatex.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you insist on using Latin Modern (`lmodern`) and not Computer Modern (standard)? If you are indifferent, then Computer Modern may save you some problems. Even though some people will say that surrender is for the weak ;-)

Comment: @Ipsen, I am happy to surrender. I am using lmodern because it is part of the default template I was copying. It looks like the standard template will solve my problem.